# Tricky: Shifting all data from Column C to last occupied column, deleting all empty cells in between and shift all data to the right

Tags: vba, excel

Referring to the below picture, I am trying to take all the data points from column C to the last occupied column (in this case, N, but in other cases, they vary, but not exceeding column U) and shift them all to column (AA) as the last right column while deleting all empty cells in between.

[image: Click here to view my sad problem]

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out here!

The intended output is as below:

[image: picture]

Comment: Shawn, read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try adjusting your's to meet these guidelines. You were downvoted by someone because you've presented your question with no proof of effort on your end. If you're unsure where to start, try looking up "last column vba" and `Range.EntireColumn` and `Range.Delete`. If you can't get working code out of that, post your efforts and where the code isn't working, and we'd all be more than glad to help you out. :)

Comment: Hi Tyeler, thanks for your feedback. I am very new here, in fact, this is my very first post and my first few VBA coding experence. Thakns for your response, I'll giveit a shot and see if it is working for me!

Comment: Just checking back, did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim row As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    With Worksheets("AlignSheetName") '<--| change "AlignSheetName" to your actual worksheet name
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(3).Resize(, .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column - 2))
            For Each row In .Rows
                arr = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(row.Value)), " ")), " ")
                row.ClearContents
                row.Cells(1, 1).Offset(, 27 - 3 - WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) - 1).Resize(, WorksheetFunction.CountA(row)).Value = arr
            Next row
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```